# Error box related to display driver using virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 14.10, gpu-driver

I am using a Windows 8.1 host, with Ubuntu 14.10 on VirtualBox. On start up, I get the following error:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element (e.g. <book>)
```

Have I done something wrong in setup? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install the VBox Extension Pack?  Can you get to the login at all?  Also, some people have had success with deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml`.  If you can't get to the gui, you can use a virtual terminal (Alt-ctrl-F1/F2/F3...).

Comment: @MartyFried My installation works fine, this error just bugs me in a window every start up.

Comment: Glad you can login; did you try deleting that config file?  Have you used the Compiz config program previously, or perhaps some other GUI configuration program? I'm not sure where the error comes from, but it must be some config file that got messed up.

Comment: @MartyFried Thanks for the advice, it works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like an error with your interface configuration, try deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml`.