# Auto Set Resolution

Tags: login, display, display-resolution, xrandr, autorun

Ok so, a while back I asked a question on how to manually set my vga resolution on Ubuntu. But I need to do this upon LOGIN (ie NOT ON BOOT). I need to run `sudo cvt 1366 768 && sudo xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync && sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00` ON LOGIN again this needs to be automatically run at login on all users no matter the desktop I choose at boot (ie Kodi, Unity, Xfce etc) Please help!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: ^ the linked dupe actually is about *log in*, as often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.desktop` file in the `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder.  Any `.desktop` file in that folder will be started as it is a system wide used folder that all users existing and new upon logging in will have applications start from.  No need to create separate startup applications / links / shortcuts for each user. More information can be found here: [FreeDesktop.Org/xdg-autostart](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html)

For the contents of the `/etc/xdg/autostart/<filename>.desktop` file add in the following:

**NOTE:**  `xrandr` does not need to be loaded with `sudo` in front of it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Some Name
Comment=Some Comment
Exec=bash -c 'cvt 1366 768 && xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00'
```

If you need a startup delay of like 10 seconds, change the `Exec` line to the following:

```
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 10 && cvt 1366 768 && xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00'
```

Your `.desktop` file should be owned by root:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/xdg/autostart/<filename>.desktop
```

and it needs to be set with `-rw-r--r--` permissions:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/xdg/autostart/<filename>.desktop
```

When you log in, this file should be called now from any user in any desktop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What would the startup delay be needed for?

Comment: @dubCraftNation I had a similar type thing with a video issue I was having, and without the delay on it, the settings never took.  I added the delay, and it worked great after that.  Try without and see if it works.

Comment: I got an error:

Comment: @dubCraftNation What error did you get?

Comment: Could not apply stored configuration for monitors                                                                                                                 Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element (e.g. <book>)

Comment: @dubCraftNation Might want to check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/552329/error-box-related-to-display-driver-using-virtualbox But it looks like you might need to delete `~/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you sooooooo much. One more thing: Can I use this method for any other software if I change the command to that software?

Comment: @dubCraftNation Yes, you sure can.  :)

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.nerdtests.com/images/ft/nq/21991e3bef.gif)

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.nerdtests.com/ft_nq.php).